# How to create a fragment of an activity in android studio?

Tags: android

I want to call a new activity when a list item is clicked from the drawer. I searched over the internet and what I got was to call the fragment of that activity. So, I wanted to know how to make a fragment of an activity.

P.S.- Sorry, if this question is silly. I'm still a noob.

Comment: i do not comprehend what exactly you are asking?

Comment: I want to call an activity when a list item is pressed from the drawer. So, I want to know how can we do that. @CaspainCaldion

Answer (score 0):

A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) the full explanation from android official developer guide.

Also on android developer guide you can find the [code](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html) to properly create and use a fragment.

Create a fragment class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_view, container, false);
    }
}
```

Then you have to add the fragment to the activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment"
              android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ExampleFragment"
              android:id="@+id/example_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="2"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally you can add the layout to your activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.item_from_exampleLayout);
    }
}
```

I took those examples from the android developer guide that i put above.

---

Anyway if i have understood your question this code should work:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

            Intent intent = new Intent(ThisClass.this, ClassToCall.class);
            startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

This will start a new activity when a list item is clicked using an intent, but it doesn't need fragments.